# Android SDK API 19 KitKat offline documentation

Tags: android, documentation

How can i get an offline version of Android SDK Version 19 (KitKat) documentation?

In API ver. 9 there is a package named "Documentation for Android SDK" that brings a local copy of API9 docs to `<sdk>/docs`, but there are no any equivalent packages for API19.

[image: No documentation packages are listed below Android 4.4 (API19)]

Comment: Are you missing an Add-on site? They show up for me. Make sure you have 2 Google Inc. repositories under  Tools -> Manage add-on sites.. there will be a bunch in there but the 2 Google Inc ones are the ones you care about

Comment: [Shows up](http://i.imgur.com/lP49xXX.png) for me.

Comment: To follow up on what I said: Verify these are the Add-on sites you have http://imgur.com/43YpDWa.jpg

Comment: @dymmeh Yes, the problem was from lack of the repositories... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but there are no any equivalent packages for API19

Yes, there are:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

You are missing most of the SDK packages, based on what's showing in your screenshot. I recommend that you go into Tools > Options in the main menu, and click the "Clear Cache" button. Then, do Packages > Reload in the main menu, to try to pick up what you are missing.