# Download the latest android SDK documentation (when SDK manager version is lagging behind)

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

The SDK manager only offers the documentation of version 23, whereas the online docs are already at 24 (see [example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html)).

Is there any way to force it to upgrade to the latest version? Any other way to download these in bulk?

The cache was cleared, as recommended in [Android SDK API 19 KitKat offline documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739872/android-sdk-api-19-kitkat-offline-documentation).

<sup>(Related: [Android offline documentation and sample codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898053/android-offline-documentation-and-sample-codes), but did not work for version 24)</sup>

[image: only docs version 23 vailable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because android N is a preview version and api 24 is not officially introduced. You should wait for some weeks. Documentations will be available for android N.

Comment: Because google wants to inform developers with the Android N api changes and release more android N apps when officially introduced