# How to use the latest Android SDK Documentation offline

Tags: android, android-studio, documentation

I know it has been asked [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893969/how-to-use-android-sdk-documentation-offline) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739872/android-sdk-api-19-kitkat-offline-documentation), but I can't find any way to work offline (on a plane) with the latest API level offline documentation (29).

Is there any official or unofficial way?

Comment: `sources-29_r01.zip` generally has all the JavaDocs.

Comment: Have you found a way? I've tried to run javadoc on sources provided by SDK manager but it fails because .aidl based java sources are missing.